# Why SpellCheck always marks words from additional dictionary (utf-8, utf-8 with BOM, UTF-16) as bad?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, spell-checking

I have this control made by **Hans Passant**, that I grabbed from here ([Trying to use the C# SpellCheck class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024798/trying-to-use-the-c-sharp-spellcheck-class)) and modified to load additional dictionary:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Forms.Integration;

namespace SoAL_TextExtractor
{
    class SpellBox : ElementHost
    {
        public SpellBox()
        {
            box = new TextBox();
            base.Child = box;
            box.TextChanged += (s, e) => OnTextChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
            Uri lex_file = new Uri(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + "\\Russian.lex");
            box.SpellCheck.CustomDictionaries.Add(lex_file);
            box.SpellCheck.IsEnabled = true;
            box.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto;
            this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
        }
        public override string Text
        {
            get { return box.Text; }
            set { box.Text = value; }
        }
        [DefaultValue(false)]
        public bool Multiline
        {
            get { return box.AcceptsReturn; }
            set { box.AcceptsReturn = value; }
        }
        [DefaultValue(false)]
        public bool WordWrap
        {
            get { return box.TextWrapping != TextWrapping.NoWrap; }
            set { box.TextWrapping = value ? TextWrapping.Wrap : TextWrapping.NoWrap; }
        }
        [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
        public new System.Windows.UIElement Child
        {
            get { return base.Child; }
            set { /* Do nothing to solve a problem with the serializer !! */ }
        }
        private TextBox box;
    }
}
```

This dictionary:

[image]

And, this result:

[image]

I tried different encodings for *.lex but words still marked as bad.

lex has the LID as needed:

```
#LID 1049
абажур
абажура
...
```

What's up?

Comment: You can't just copy somebody else's code and repost it as though it is your own.  Attribution is required, look at the bottom of the page for details.

Comment: @HansPassant - excuse me? Where did I said it's my code? All I said is "I have this control". I know this is grabbed from another answer, but I never told this is mine. I using it, I have problems with it and I showing here what I have.

Comment: The license doesn't say anything about that.  It is an exceedingly simple rule, when you repost somebody else's work then you **must** attribute.  Always.  Please take care of it.

Comment: Oh huh, so you are the author. I added credits to my questions. Also, question solved by removing LID from lex.

Comment: @Kosmos I tested removing the LID and that didn't solve the problem.  It resulted in none of the words being underlined as misspelled.

Comment: @Loathing - Well, this is the differences that we probably have: 1 - **I do not set: `box.Language = /*to anything*/;`.** 2 - **My lex is saved in UTF-16, while you said it's in 1252 code page**. On msdn said that: **If the locale is not specified, the dictionary applies to all languages.**... So, i don't know how, but the SpellCheck is work for me as expected.

Comment: I confirm UTF-16 with no language setting and no LID works. Surprising how giving more information causes it to not work as one would expect. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get French working by doing the following:

- saving file using 1252 encoding
- setting the language on the text box
- setting the #LID to 1036 in the lex file

Testing using a file containing: ééé

e.g.

```
box.Language = System.Windows.Markup.XmlLanguage.GetLanguage("fr");
String text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(lex_file.AbsolutePath, Encoding.UTF8);
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(lex_file.AbsolutePath, text, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252));
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work for Russian. It appears only 4 languages are supported by default.  See [Does SpellCheck .Net class support russian language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6361219/does-spellcheck-net-class-support-russian-language) for more information.